# Create CSS Cards from PHP array?

Tags: php, css, arrays

Anyone knows how to do create multiple cards looping through a PHP array?

For example, I have 5 `friend` with 5 `description` corrresponding each friend (from a mysqli table) saved in `$friendList`.

So I want, for each row, to create and show a card with the friend as a header and its description as the content of the card.

This would be the loop

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($friendList, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       // $row['friend'];
       // $row['description'];
 }
```

but then, I do not know how to create the cards with the variables obtained:

Comment: you are doing good. whats the issue. in the loop, you can get the values

Comment: but where do I create the cards?

Comment: What do you mean by card? What is a card? Just do `echo $row['friend'];` to display the value of friend. And do the same for description.

Comment: inside the loop, create the `cards`

Comment: This is a CSS card https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_cards.asp

Comment: Ok then you have to `echo` the HTML that it expects. So do `echo '<div class="w3-card">
  <p>'.$row['friend'].'</p>
</div>'`

Comment: And you have to include the w3.css file. Did you include it? You can get it from here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.asp. The instructions to use it are on that page.

Comment: do you have image as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have `$friendList` variable already defined and it is a `mysqli_result` object, here's how you can do it:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($friendList, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
<div class="w3-card-4 test">
  <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="Avatar">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <h4><b><?php echo $row["friend"] ?></b></h4>   
  <p><?php echo $row["description"] ?></p>    
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Feel free to ask any questions :-)